# Are there unified cure modeling (aka split population modeling) papers in labor economics?

Tags: survival, econometrics, cure-models

Does anyone know if there are unified cure models (aka split population models) in time-until-employment studies that combine the mixture cure approach with the promotion time approach as described in this paper: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1471082x0800900202

Comment: If you have not already, I recommend posting the question on the Economics site: https://economics.stackexchange.com.